# Converting integer to Roman numeral in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to write a function that converts an integer to a string representation of the integer in roman numerals. This is the code so far:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Kata {
  function solution(uint n) returns (string) {
    // Convert the positive integer to a Roman Numeral
    uint len = Length(n);
    string[] numerals = Numerals(n);
    
    string roman = '';
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
      roman = Concatenate(roman, numerals[i]);
    return roman;
    }
  }
  
  function Length(uint x) returns(uint) {
    uint l = 0;
    while (x>0) {
      x / 10;
      l ++;
    }
    return l;
  }
    
  function Digits(uint x) returns(uint[]) {
    uint l = Length(x);
    uint d;
    uint[] ds;
      
    for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
      d = x / (10**(l-i-1));
      ds.push(d);
      x -= (d*(10**(l-i-1)));
    }
    return ds;
  }
      
  function Numerals(uint x) returns(string[]) {
    uint l = Length(x);
    uint[] ds = Digits(x);
    string[] s;
        
    mapping(uint => string) units;
    units[0] = "";
    units[1] = "I";
    units[2] = "II";
    units[3] = "III";
    units[4] = "IV";
    units[5] = "V";
    units[6] = "VI";
    units[7] = "VII";
    units[8] = "VIII";
    units[9] = "IX";
    
    mapping(uint => string) tens;
    tens[0] = "";
    tens[1] = "X";
    tens[2] = "XX";
    tens[3] = "XXX";
    tens[4] = "XL";
    tens[5] = "L";
    tens[6] = "LX";
    tens[7] = "LXX";
    tens[8] = "LXXX";
    tens[9] = "XC";
    
    mapping(uint => string) hundreds;
    hundreds[0] = "";
    hundreds[1] = "C";
    hundreds[2] = "CC";
    hundreds[3] = "CCC";
    hundreds[4] = "CD";
    hundreds[5] = "D";
    hundreds[6] = "DC";
    hundreds[7] = "DCC";
    hundreds[8] = "DCCC";
    hundreds[9] = "CM";
    
    mapping(uint => string) thousands;
    thousands[0] = "";
    thousands[1] = "M";
    thousands[2] = "MM";
    thousands[3] = "MMM";
       
    enum d {thousands, hundreds, tens, units}
          
    for (i=0; i<l, i++) {
      s.push(d(4-l+i)[ds[i]]);
    }
    return s;
  }
        
  function Concatenate(string a, string b) returns(string) {
    a_ = byte(a);
    b_ = byte(b);
    a_ *= (2**(b_.length));
    a_ += b_;
    return string(a_);
  }
}
```

The procedure in my head was to turn an integer into an integer array of its digits. Then using a mapping of 'digits to Roman numeral symbols', convert the integer array into a string array. I tried to use an enum to control that conversion. Afterwards the plan was to concatenate the strings in the string array together.

The first problem I'm having is `ParserError: Expected primary expression.` and I have no idea why. Can anyone explain that? Secondly, I'm wondering if anything else is *obviously* wrong in my implementation or approach? (I'm a beginner to Solidity, with most of my programming experience in Python). And, as far as I know, I can't use any external libraries to help.

Comment: I don't know solidity: does it give you a line number or any indication where the error is? The online compiler on soliditylang.org doesn't, which is pretty useless, but it expects a different language version too - which requires 'memory' annotations on the strings etc. - though. I'd try building it up one function at a time until you can make it compile, which looks like Length then Digits then Numerals or Concatenate, then solution. It's also not obvious to me what the entry point here is, but maybe you're just declaring a function to call?

Comment: You've also got the return roman in the wrong place in solution, and you're not declaring the type for your i iterators.

Comment: On the general approach: the way I've done it in the past is declare a list of number and letter pairs including the single subtraction cases: 1000=M 900=CM 500=D 400=CD 100=C 90=XC 50=L 40=XL 10=X 9=IX 5=V 4=IV 1=I. Then work through the list: at each stage subtract as many of that number as you can and output that many copies of the group as needed before moving on. But there's nothing wrong with this way, as long as you only have to cope with inputs up to 4000.

Comment: @Rup The error is in in the line that says "enum d {thousands, hundreds, tens, units}" towards the end of the script.